# Assigning sequential numbers to dates in SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, netezza, gaps-and-islands, date-arithmetic

I am trying to bucket dates that fall within a 30-day window of each other in SQL. For each ID number in the example data below, how can I assign a bucket number that increases by 1 every time there's more than a 30-day gap between adjacent dates?

Example data:

```
create table dates_bucket (ID integer, DATE date);
insert into dates_bucket (ID, DATE)
values
('123', '2019-04-04'),
('123', '2019-04-06'),
('123', '2019-09-09'),
('123', '2019-09-10'),
('123', '2019-10-01'),
('123', '2019-11-30'),
('345', '2013-03-12'),
('345', '2013-05-23'),
('345', '2014-09-03'),
('345', '2019-10-23'),
('345', '2019-10-25');
```

I need the output to look like this:

```
ID    DATE           ROW_NUM
123   2019-04-04     1
123   2019-04-06     1
123   2019-09-09     2
123   2019-09-10     2
123   2019-10-01     2
123   2019-11-30     3
345   2013-03-12     1
345   2013-05-23     2
345   2014-09-03     3
345   2019-10-23     4
345   2019-10-25     4
```

In case it's relevant, I am working in Netezza.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem, where islands are adjacent dates with less than one month in between. I would recommend `lag()` to get the previous date, and a cumulative `sum()` that increases a gap of more than 30 days is met:

```
select id, date, 
    sum(case when date <= lag_date + interval '30 day' then 0 else 1 end)
        over(partition by id order by date) as grp
from (
    select d.*,
        lag(date) over(partition by id order by date) lag_date
    from dates_buckets d
) d
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I thought sum might have a role but couldn't figure out how to put the pieces together.